# JuliaでStatsPlotsを用いてグラフを描画する際にPyErrorが発生してしまう

Tags: julia

JuliaでStatsPlotsを用いてグラフを描画しようとし、以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
using StatsPlots
@df df plot(:x軸, :ｙ軸
    ,title="タイトル"
    ,xlabel = "x軸"
    ,ylabel = "y軸")
```

すでにdfにはcsvデータを

```
df = CSV.read(loc * filename, DataFrame, header = true, delim = ",")
```

と読み込んでおります。
しかしながら、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= C:\Users\私の名前\.julia\packages\PyCall\BD546\src\pyfncall.jl:43 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr, kw))))) <class 'AttributeError'>
AttributeError("'Line2D' object has no property 'title'")
```

ちなみに、下記のように記述した場合には問題なく動きました。

```
using StatsPlots
@df df plot(:x軸, :y軸)
```

このエラーを解消するにはどのようにすればよいか、どなたかお知恵を貸していただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

タイプミスだと思います。

```
@df df plot(:x軸, :ｙ軸
```

の`:ｙ軸`を`:y軸`に変更すればうまくいくはずです。

ファイルの内容が不明ですが、@df df plot(:x軸, :y軸)がうまくいっているのであれば、`ｙ`軸ではなく`y`軸が正しいと思います。

Comment: すみません、質問文の方がタイプミスでした。
"'Line2D' object has no property 'title'"とあるのでtitleいかに何かミスがあるのかと思っているのですが、なかなかエラーが特定できず……

Comment: plotのその他パラメータに問題はないと思います。環境やインストールしたpkgの問題かもしれません。julia -version、OS(Winだと思いますが)、CSVファイルの内容、実際に使用したCSV.readのコードなど再現できる情報を提示すると回答が得られるかもしれません。WSL2の私の環境で動かしてみましたがエラーは発生しませんでした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私の方でも完全にまっさらなワークシートに上記のコードを入力したらうまく描画できました。
エラーが発生した際は、StatsPlotsを使用する前に
`using PyPlots`
とPyPlotを用いて図表を描画したのですが、PyPlotとStatsPlotsが競合してしまってうまく作動しないということはあり得るのでしょうか？また、その場合に一度usingで指定したpkgを取り消してStatsPlotsを使用することはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: usingの取り消しはできないようです。usingは使わないものまでロードされるようなので、使うものだけimportするのが良さそうです。私はJuliaに詳しくありません。この質問は自己回答して、新たに別の質問を上げてはいかがでしょうか？